# Can I check my luggage the night before the flight in Porto Airport?

Tags: luggage, airports, portugal, porto, opo

I'll be having an early morning flight (6 am) from [Porto Airport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porto_Airport) (OPO) with Lufthansa.

**Will I be able to drop my luggage** (assume I checked in online) **the night before?**

Comment: Many international hub airports have "twilight" or "night before" luggage drop, but it's not common for smaller airports. Can't find any info on OPO

Comment: The last LH flight appears to leave at [16:40](http://www.ana.pt/en-US/Aeroportos/porto/Porto/Departures/FlightInformation/Pages/FlightInformation.aspx) and that may not be a daily flight. It's possible that you could get there and find the check-in counter closed, even if they would otherwise be willing to accept the bags early.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Lufthansa Official Twitter](https://twitter.com/lufthansa/status/739045008305717248)

> "We are not offering a late night check in in Porto, please bring your
>   luggage in the morning. /Nina"

So no, you need to get rid of your luggage on the morning of your flight.

Answer (score 6):

For Lufthansa in general, the website http://www.lufthansa.com/de/en/Check-in-Information allows you to select the airport you are flying from to get information about check-in possibilities. If late night check-in is possible, it is mentioned under "On-airport services". For Porto, it is not available (I double checked by selecting Frankfurt, where I know it is available, and it showed up)